# python multicore queue randomly hangs for no reason, despite queue size being tiny

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

in python here is my multiprocessing setup. I subclassed the Process method and gave it
a queue and some other fields for pickling/data purposes.

This strategy works about 95% of the time, the other 5% for an unknown reason the queue just hangs and it never finishes (it's common that 3 of the 4 cores finish their jobs and the last one takes forever so I have to just kill the job).

I am aware that queue's have a fixed size in python, or they will hang. My queue only stores one character strings... the id of the processor, so it can't be that.

Here is the exact line where my code halts:

```
res = self._recv()
```

Does anyone have ideas? The formal code is below.
Thank you.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from multiprocessing import cpu_count as num_cores
import codecs, cPickle

class Processor(Process):

    def __init__(self, queue, elements, process_num):
        super(Processor, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue
        self.elements = elements
        self.id = process_num

    def job(self):

        ddd = []

        for l in self.elements:

            obj = ... heavy computation ...

            dd = {}
            dd['data'] = obj.data
            dd['meta'] = obj.meta
        ddd.append(dd)

        cPickle.dump(ddd, codecs.open(
            urljoin(TOPDIR, self.id+'.txt'), 'w'))

        return self.id

    def run(self):
        self.queue.put(self.job())



 if __name__=='__main__':

        processes = []

        for i in range(0, num_cores()):

            q = Queue()
            p = Processor(q, divided_work(), process_num=str(i))
            processes.append((p, q))
            p.start()

        for val in processes:

            val[0].join()
            key = val[1].get() 

            storage = urljoin(TOPDIR, key+'.txt')

            ddd = cPickle.load(codecs.open(storage , 'r'))

            .. unpack ddd process data ...
```

Comment: `res = self._recv()` doesn't look like an error message..

Comment: it was the line my code hangs on, misworded

Comment: The line `res = self._recv()` is not in the code you show. Also, could you post the error message again?

Comment: there is no error message, my code just hangs. When I press ctrl-c, I can see that it's hanging on res = self._recv().

Comment: There is no `res = self._recv()` in the code you posted.

Comment: Because that line is internal within python's multiprocessing module!

Comment: In that case print the console output around the `res = self._recv()` like you did before. Also try my suggested answer below.

Comment: You aren't protecting against something going terribly wrong in Processor. If "heavy computation" raises an exception, nothing is written to the queue and your parent will hang. Use some combo of try/except/finally in the run() method to make sure that something is always posted to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `time.sleep(0.001)` at the beginning of your `run()` method.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I will do it. But can you explain your reasoning?

Comment: I had a similar problem once, it also seems to have worked for [this guy](http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/multiprocessing-what-am-I-doing-wrong-td4499430.html). Unfortunately I don't have a more satisfactory explanation.

Comment: i'll reply back of the results, btw it's just a bit odd to me because my job method takes a long time, like 5 minutes. Do you think pausing for a msecond will change anything. Weird! Thanks for the reply though

Comment: I can't be sure, just try and find out, it might not work, in which case more investigation will be needed!

Comment: ouch, it is still hanging :\ maybe it's my logic in the computations that's taking forever

Comment: Can't you test that independently?

Comment: I just checked, it's not my logic actually. Something is wrong with the processes

Comment: Mike wanna go into a private chat together? You definitely have more experience with processing than I do :P

Answer (score 0):

From my experience

```
time.sleep(0.001)
```

Is by far not long enough.

I had a similar problem. It seems to happen if you call `get()` or `put()` on a queue "too early". I guess it somehow fails to initialize quick enough. Not entirely sure, but I'm speculating that it might have something to do with the ways a queue might use the underlying operating system to pass messages. It started happening to me after I started using BeautifulSoup and lxml and it affected totally unrelated code.

My solution is a little big ugly but it's simple and it works:

```
import time

def run(self):
    error = True
    while error:
        self.queue.put(self.job())
        error = False
    except EOFError:
        print "EOFError. retrying..."
        time.sleep(1)
```

On my machine it usually retries twice during application start-up and afterwards never again. You need to do that inside of sender AND receiver since this error will occur on both sides.